# Loop through data frames to produce new column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have 10 data frames (Shape1,Shape 2,Shape 3 etc.), each containing the same the column names. How do i for loop this command through the 10 data frames so each contains a new column called integration?

```
Shape1$Integration<-cumtrapz(Shape1$Time, Shape1$CA)
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R, you can create a list of dataframe using `mget`, loop over each and create a new column with `transform`.

```
lapply(mget(paste0("Shape", 1:10)), function(x) 
        transform(x, Integration = cumtrapz(Time, CA)))
```

---

In `tidyverse` that can be done as

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mget(paste0("Shape", 1:10)), ~.x %>% mutate(Integration = cumtrapz(Time, CA)))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, thats great and worked perfectly. Using your first example, how do i then bind Integration to the original 10 Shape dataframes?

Comment: @Crabbe1 you can store the output from `lapply` in an object. say `list_df`, `list_df <- lapply(mget(paste0("Shape", 1:10)), function(x) 
  transform(x, Integration = cumtrapz(Time, CA)))`. Then do `list2env(list_df, .GlobalEnv)` you'll get 10 different dataframes again.